# spl-token CLI unexpected behaviour

Tags: spl-token, token, associated-token-account, mint, spl-token-cli

I'm writing a bash script to do some creating of mints, associated token accounts and minting.

What I'm trying to do is, create a mint with a mint_authority `A` keypair, and then create a associated token account for specified owner `B` and then mint some tokens to the specified owner `B`.

But when I'm trying to mint using the following command,

```
spl-token mint <TOKEN_MINT> 1 --owner <B_PUBKEY> --fee-payer <A_KEYPAIR_PATH> -u devnet --mint_authority <A_KEYPAIR_PATH>
```

I get an error that says,

```
error: The argument '--mint-authority <KEYPAIR>' was provided more than once, but cannot be used multiple times
```

And, if I set my default keypair to `A_KEYPAIR_PATH` using `solana config set -k <A_KEYPAIR_PATH>` and then run the following command,

```
spl-token mint <TOKEN_MINT> 1 --owner <B_PUBKEY> --fee-payer <A_KEYPAIR_PATH> -u devnet
```

I get an error saying,

```
error: missing signature for supplied pubkey: <B_PUBKEY>
```

Now, what I don't understand is that why would I require a signature for `B` when the `mint_authority` is `A`?

And the signature of `A` should be available since I'm either setting the `--mint_authority` flag or setting the default keypair as `A`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, so there's this issue to track its resolution: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/3684

In the meantime, to get around this, you can avoid using the `--owner` flag and instead specify the owner's associated-token-account address, ie:

```
spl-token mint <TOKEN_MINT> 1 <ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_FOR_B_PUBKEY> --mint-authority <A_KEYPAIR_PATH>
```

Answer (score 1):

after some discussion we decided `--owner` is working as intended, as it typically refers to the authority the main action is tied to or taken under. ive added a `--recipient-owner` flag to `mint` that covers your usecase